# "Splitting" the output of a RLE (groupby) depending on a defined value ( the "character" to split the RLE on )

Tags: python, functional-programming, list-comprehension, arrays, run-length-encoding

Consider the "string" ( treat it as an array of digits )

```
0 0 1 8 8 8 1 0
```

The RLE ( "groupby" ) is:

```
[(0,2), (1, 1), (8,3), (1, 1), (0, 1)]
```

We then enrich the above RLE with the sum of the run lengths of the previous elements.

Hence, the enriched version of the above becomes:

```
[(0, (0,2)), (0+2, (1, 1)), (0+2+1, (8,3)), (0+1+2+3, (1, 1)), (0+1+2+3+1, (0, 1))]
```

The "string" split on 1:

```
0 0 , 8 8 8 , 0
```

RLE split on 1

```
[(0,2)] , [(8,3)] , [(0, 1)]
```

The "string" split on 8:

```
0 0 1 , , , 1 0
```

RLE split on 8

```
[(0,2), (1, 1)] , , , [(1, 1), (0, 1)]
```

Note : In my examples, I have cited the "RLE split on Z" lists without enriching them. This would not be so. I left them out to reduce clutter. For example, the "RLE split on 1" should really be treated as:

```
[(0, (0,2))] , [(0+2+1, (8,3))] , [(0+1+2+3+1, (0, 1)]
```

**How can I achieve this "RLE split" on Z** ( = 1, 8; in this case )

It's fine to leave out empty arrays ( after split ).

Perhaps a clever list comp.? ( it seems a little easier to solve with a for loop with an append nested within )

Comment: I'm confused. Is an expression like `0+2+1` supposed to be a string or do you just want `3`?

Comment: Just 3 - I wanted to break things down to be readable. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Suppose RLE=[(0,2), (1,1), (8,3), (4,2), (1,1), (0,1)]; Should the result be [(0, (0,2))] , [(0+2+1, (8,3), **(4,2)** )] , [(0+2+1+3+2+1, (0, 1)] or [(0, (0,2))] , [(0+2+1, (8,3)), **(0+2+1+3, (4,2))** ] , [(0+2+1+3+2+1, (0, 1)]

Comment: To get that RLE, the original array needs to be `a = [0, 0, 1, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 1, 1, 0]`.

In that case here is what I have

`get_rle(a) -> [[(0, (0, 2)), (2, (1, 1)), (3, (8, 3)), (6, (4, 2)), (8, (1, 2)), (10, (0, 1))]]
get_rle(a, 1) -> [[(0, (0, 2))], [(3, (8, 3)), (6, (4, 2))], [(10, (0, 1))]]
get_rle(a, 4) -> [[(0, (0, 2)), (2, (1, 1)), (3, (8, 3))], [(8, (1, 2)), (10, (0, 1))]]
get_rle(a, 8) -> [[(0, (0, 2)), (2, (1, 1))], [(6, (4, 2)), (8, (1, 2)), (10, (0, 1))]]
`

Comment: Just thought using the same start index for one group will reduce nesting, anyway already made it. Check the answer below or this: inOneLine=lambda dat,n:[list(g) for k,g in itertools.groupby((zip((sum(tuple(zip(*((k,len(tuple(g))) for k,g in itertools.groupby(dat))))[1][:i]) for i in range(len(tuple(zip(*((k,len(tuple(g))) for k,g in itertools.groupby(dat))))[1]))) ,(zip(*tuple(zip(*((k,len(tuple(g))) for k,g in itertools.groupby(dat)))))))),lambda x:x[1][0]!=n) if k]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for show the way how, I strongly advise you not to use this

"elegant" ugly way:

```
>>> data
[0, 0, 1, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 1, 0]
>>> def fromDataToSplitRLE(dat,n):
    RLE=[(k,len(tuple(g))) for k,g in itertools.groupby(dat)]
    tmp=tuple(zip(*RLE))
    return [list(g) for k,g in itertools.groupby((zip((sum(tmp[1][:i]) for i in range(len(tmp[1]))) ,(zip(*tmp)))),lambda x:x[1][0]!=n) if k]

>>> fromDataToSplitRLE(data,1)
[[(0, (0, 2))], [(3, (8, 3)), (6, (4, 2))], [(9, (0, 1))]]
```

Comment: @aaronasterling: well I got it misunderstood. Will improve it.

Comment: I would very much like to see you accomplish this with a list comprehension.

Comment: Note that this requires two groupby calls. However, it does the splitting correctly without any further processing, whereas aaron's will require a further pass on None.

Comment: @Kabie : You have put in a lot of effort into this, but your function is 3 times slower and does 6 times as many function calls as aaron's final version. The code I had written originally does twice as many calls, but it takes almost the same time. However, based on the sheer amount of effort you have put into this, I am accepting yours ( the one you posted in comments above ) as the answer.

Comment: @PoorLuzer: Never write a function like the one in my comment. Every return value used twice or more should be stored in variable, not call the function again. I did it just for write it in one line and aaronasterling already gave the appropriate way.

Comment: @Kabie : I agree. You did take up a challenge, and delivered. Good work.

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools

def get_rle(list_of_digits, split_on=None):
    count = 0
    rle = []
    active_group = []
    rle_app = rle.append
    for item, group in itertools.groupby(list_of_digits):
        L = len(list(group))
        if item == split_on:
            rle_app(active_group)
            active_group = []
        else:
            active_group.append((count, (item, L)))
        count += L

    rle_app(active_group)
    return rle

list_of_digits = map(int, '0 0 1 8 8 8 1 0'.split())
print get_rle(list_of_digits)
print get_rle(list_of_digits, 8)
print get_rle(list_of_digits, 1)

aaron@aaron-laptop:~/code/tmp$ python rle.py
[[(0, (0, 2)), (2, (1, 1)), (3, (8, 3)), (6, (1, 1)), (7, (0, 1))]]
[[(0, (0, 2)), (2, (1, 1))], [(6, (1, 1)), (7, (0, 1))]]
[[(0, (0, 2))], [(3, (8, 3))], [(7, (0, 1))]]
```

Comment: I had this written already ( and without the None. Notice I mentioned *"It's fine to leave out empty arrays ( after split )."* ) That's why I commented *"( it seems a little easier to solve with a for loop with an append nested within )"* - **I am looking for something faster - like a list compr.** Ideas?

Comment: @PoorLuzer. See my note at the end. I just edited it in. This will make it go significantly faster.

Comment: In (count, (item, L)), count should be the start index, so plus L after the if statement

Comment: Your latest version captures all my requirements. Great work. I was amazed to find that your final version beat my original function ( which was almost what you had written first ) by *half* as many calls. I do not know whether that is solely due to local binding though, but I find no other difference **(though it does seem that `L = sum(1 for unused in group)` is *slower* than `L = len(list(group))`**!.

Comment: @PoorLuzer, take out the local bindings for `active_app.append` and see if not having to reassign it for every new group makes it faster. My thinking (untested) is that if the groups are longer than ten or so elements on average, the cost of making the local bindings will pay for themselves. If the length is smaller than that, then it's probably a bad move. I mainly put it in to show that it can be done.

Comment: Oh - that extra piece of code that I had means making this little change to the last line of your function at `rle_app(active_group)` to `if len( active_group ) : rle_app(active_group)`. That implies the difference is only due to local binding? WOW! Binding a global function locally turns the number of calls into half?!

Comment: In case anyone is interested, we can also get a flat list using `[ (o, (s, r)) for seq in get_rle(...) for (o, (s, r)) in seq ]`